# Guzzle 401 Unauthorized using post method

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I wanted to convert all my api calls using Guzzle 6.0(before was with curl_multi). however When I make a post request it comes with Unauthorized response.

Working:

```
$url = "http://192.168.101.10/WebConnect/search.asp?";
$request_data = 'CID=test&PWD=test&ORD=;0451103144;;1;;';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);

$reply = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
   print curl_error($ch);
} else {
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($reply);
   echo '</pre>';
}
curl_close($ch);
```

using  Guzzle 6.0

```
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->post($url, [
         'timeout' => 30,
         'body' => $request_data,
    ]);

    echo $res->getStatusCode();
    echo $res->getHeader('content-type');
    echo $res->getBody();
```

> Error:
>
> **Client error: `POST http://192.168.101.10/WebConnect/search.asp?` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xml (truncated...)
```

I tried with

```
'auth' => ['test','test'] //doesnot work either
```

Also I tried to add headers but it doesnot work same error

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-type' => 'text/plain;charset="utf-8"',
    'Accept' => 'text/plain',
    'Content-length' => strlen($test)
);
```

and also with

```
    $headers = array(
        'Accept' => 'text/html',
        'Content-Type' => 'text/html',
    );
```

and also i tried to submit the separate the params

```
$requestBody = array(
     'CID' => 'test',
     'PWD' => 'test',
     'ORD' => ';0451103144;;1;'
 ); 

 $request = $client->post($url,
    array(
    'headers' => $headers,
    'form_params' => $requestBody
   ));
```

Why does it says `<html xml (truncated...)` xml..?? When I specifically mentioned its a `text/plain` or `text/html`

Comment: Sounds strange... 
Try the following way:
1) Create client `$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();`
2) Create a request object. `$request = new Request('POST', $url, [], urldecode($request_data));`
2) Send request and print response `print_r($client->send($request));`

Comment: I guess you're using the wrong Request Option. Have a further look at http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html?highlight=request. I'm not so familar with Guzzle client, but i think guzzle does not expects an url formatted query but an array. I can imagine, guzzle uses `http_build_query()` internally in order to convert objects or arrays. Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: The request and the response itself are quite strange but that how our partners have set up..... i have also tried to submit the params not as body.... still it doesnot work... `$requestBody = array(
'CID' => 'test',
'PWD' => 'test',
'ORD' => ';0451103144;;1;'
);` and then `$request = $client->post($url,
array(
'headers' => $headers,
'form_params' => $requestBody
));`

Comment: I've noticed another issue. In your working example you're using the variable `$test`: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $test);` but in your code `$test` is not defined. It might be that you send an other POST body in your working code snipped as in your Guzzle example...

Comment: its typo.. updated the question

Comment: Try the debug option:
`$client->request('POST', $url, ['debug' => true], $request_d‌​ata);`

Comment: I tried with `$client->request('P‌​OST', $url, ['debug' => true','form_param'=> $request_d‌​ata);` it now results in Server Error with **500** but i do get the data using only curl. [DEBUG RESULT](http://i68.tinypic.com/211mayt.jpg).... Its is strange that the content-length is different from the url-encoded content-length

Comment: I have no further ideas. I would suggest to debug into the Guzzle code using xdebug or similar tools.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for your help :)